# JWT Authentication How to verify http requests in a separate API project not the AuthServer project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

After reading several articles especially [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management#users-controller-cs)

I made my own ASP.NET Core solution which has

> 1 project(AuthServer) for `Authentication` and `Authorisation`, and
>
> 1 project (WebApi) for the rest of APIs in my whole projects.

**Question is:
How to verify http requests in my WebApi project?**

I know once an user is authenticated, the client will hold the token and for the subsequent requests, they all need to pass int the Token and on the server side, it somehow verifies these requests by this piece of code which is in Startup.cs for the AuthServer Project:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x=> {
            x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                    var userId = context.Principal.Identity.Name;
                    var user = userService.GetById(userId);
                    if(user == null)
                    {
                        context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
            
        });
```

But for the WebApi project, what I need to do to verify the token?
I would imagine it would not be just placing an annotation(**[Authorize]**) on a controller or an action like:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{ ....}
```

Then what I should do to verify the token in my WebApi project?
By calling the Authenticate endpoint in my `AuthServer` project every time when a request comes in and then execute the code in the WebApi?

Comment: Normally you would have the client side call your Authentication API first, get the token from the Authenticate endpoint, and then the client would include that token as a header value (bearer token) in the request anytime you go to your WebApi for a request.  I think if you Google any kind of "JWT ASP.NET Core" you should find examples of how to look for incoming auth tokens on your WebApi side.

Comment: hi @BenKrueger thanks for reply. I searched again, but all the articles still talking the implementation of AutheServer and WebApi projects together as 1 project.

Comment: @Franva it seems you may want to run 2 separate ASP.NET applications, one will handle authorization, and 2nd the remaining logic?

Comment: @Andriy yes. That's the impression I got after reading many articles. Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: I’d recommend you to look at [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io/). Using it you can set up a proper authentication provider (as a separate server) and a secured API server which you can then consume authenticated. The [quickstarts documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/0_overview.html) will also cover your situation.

Comment: hi @poke thanks for the help. the IdentityServer and OICD was the 1st thing I read through, but I think it's overkilled. I don't need that much overhead, what I need is just a simple solution of auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to run 2 separate ASP.NET applications.
You can validate requests, which come to `WebApi` by sending http requests to your `AuthServer`.
You can create a custom attribute, which will do the job.
In WebApi project:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class YourCustomAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    { 
        public YourCustomAuthAttribute(
            : base(typeof(AuthFilter))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] {
               // arguments gets passed to AuthFilter contructor,

            };
        }
    }

    public class AuthFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

        public AuthFilter()
        {
        }

        //Change it to fit your logic
        public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authorizationHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authtorization"];
            if (authorizationHeader == StringValues.Empty)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
            else
            {
                var response = await http.GetAsync(
                    "your AuthServer address/login/?token=" + authorizationHeader.ToString(),
                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead //because we want only status code
                );
                if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a following endpoint in `LoginController` in AuthServer project

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ValidateToken(string token)
{
   //your logic here
}
```

Attribute usage is the same as `[Authorize]`.

Check out this link too (I have used some code from it) https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/jwt-authentication-microservices-net/. 
It's shown how to validate a Jwt token by hand.

You might also need to setup CORS in AuthServer project, to allow WebApi make a requests
`Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
        }
```

Comment: thanks Andriy, which project should I create this custom attribute?  AuthServer or WebApi?  Where is the YourCustomAttribute used in the example?

Comment: @Franva, attribute is declared and used inside WebApi project

Comment: How about which project should I create this custom attribute? Thanks for updating the answer, yes I have set up the CORS :)

Comment: @Franva , well , create an attribute class in WebApi project

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours reading, I found an article talking about whether to have AuthServer separated from your API Server.

In huge commercial projects, it's definitely better to have them separated, but in my case, it's just my side project, so I ended up with build them together to save energy.